# How to put multiple flatlists in one global scrollview in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-scrollview

I want to add about 3 flatlist in my app's homepage. There's a global scrollview that wraps all the children. I have read other answers about using only one list and one flatlist. That can't be done here and it will make things messy. And I know about ListHeaderComponent and ListFooterComponent but since there are multiple flatlists with multiple datalists I can't do this either.

So how do I get this done. I'm kind of new to react native. I can do this easily with flutter.

Comment: Is there no way to do that in react native? I can do this easily in flutter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SectionList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist). See the line

> Heterogeneous data and item rendering support

Comment: Well, if there's no better way I will have to try sectionlist. But thanks anyway.